# AWS transit gateway/AWS VPN tunnel never goes up

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, devops

This is the first time I've tried to setup the AWS VPN attached to a transit gateway. I've tested using openswan and it worked like a charm. But the issue is now I am trying to set it up for our premise network which is behind a NAT device. I am trying to comprehend why the tunnel are still down and the network people from the onpremise side are not helping much (they said they've configured the customer gateway and that's it) .

Basically they have given me a CIDR range (/30) to where I need to NAT first all traffics before routing them to onprem and with that CIDR range I could not even create a subnet (invalid CIDR range for the subnet). I have also gotten the static routes which I've added to the transit gateway routes.

Is there a way to NAT traffic from a VPC to a specific network (AWS side in my case to 10.x.x.x/30) before sending the traffic over the tunnel to onpremise. I could not find a way to setup that up.

And also the onpremise network people are not helping much since they said they've setup everything on their side and waiting for me to bring the tunnel up. Is there something am I missing, in my previous AWS VPN setup, the initiator to bring the tunnel was always from the customer gateway side.

/palmer

Answer (score 0):

In this case the vpn will be always initiate from the on premise side for completion.
you need to prepare a cgw and create a s2s vpn connection with those cgw and share the config information s2s with your on premise colleague .
Also for nat in vpc you can use the nat gateway for one way nat.

Comment: Can you tell if you configured the openswan with transit gateway?

Comment: Hey Kaushik Pal , I've configured the transit gateway using openswan for testing purpose